# ggplot2 Graph Colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my current script for my graph (xlab/ylab/title not labeled yet)

```
AbundanceByZone <- ggplot(CabrilloData,
                          aes(x=Zone,y=Abundance,fill=Zone))+
  stat_summary(fun="sum", geom="bar")+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  ggtitle("")

AbundanceByZone
```

This gives me a basic bar ggplot, with normal fill colors (image below).  I am wondering how to edit this script in order to add my own colors either from wesanderson or RColorBrewer.

[image: Bar Graph]

I haven't been able to figure out how to embed the code into this script.  What would I have to add into this script in order to add in my own colors?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not add data to your question, I will explain you how to do what you want with an example using `iris` dataset. The key is to use `scale_fill_manual()` and setting the desired colors. I will be using `wesandersen` colors:

```
library(wesanderson)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=Species,group=Species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Rushmore1"))
```

Output:

[image]

In your could it should work next:

```
library(wesanderson)
library(tidyverse)
#Code2
AbundanceByZone<-ggplot(CabrilloData,aes(x=Zone,y=Abundance,fill=Zone))+
  stat_summary(fun="sum",geom="bar")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Rushmore1"))+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  ggtitle("")
```

You can test other colors for sure.